# Test if an XML node with a specific name has a value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do a test on a node that has a name to see if it has a value and I am struggling to get the syntax right.

XML

```
<report pages="1" currentpage="1" name="br_rber_cms_future_stock2" rowfrom="1" rowto="4">
  <arguments>
    <arg name="arg1">7581</arg>
    <arg name="arg2">BGG1057</arg>
    <arg name="arg3"/>
    <arg name="arg4"/>
    <arg name="arg5"/>
    <arg name="arg6"/>
    <arg name="arg7"/>
    <arg name="arg8"/>
    <arg name="arg9"/>
    <arg name="arg10"/>
  </arguments>
</report>
```

I'm currently using this in the XSLT, but I'm not getting much joy:

```
<xsl:if test="//arg[name='arg2'] !=''">
    <xsl:call-template name="row"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

`arg name="arg2"` will always exist, but I only need to call the template if it has a value.

Any help would be great. Also it's my first post, so I apologize if I may have missed anything, please say and I'll add.

TIA

Comment: Difficult to answer without context - perhaps `test="string(//arg[@name='arg2'])"`?

Comment: Your xpaht should do, only you are missed a `@` before name. But perhaps better would be to use  `test="//arg[@name='arg2'][text()]"`

Comment: Ahh, @!  That has resolved it, thank you.